# FPC/Lazarus and Android development?

Tags: java, android, pascal, lazarus, fpc

**Hi,**

---

I've heard something about component to **Lazarus to develop Android apps**... I **understand pascal** very well and Im not sure if it will be easier to **learn Java**, or **make applications in Pascal** ... What do you think? It will be better to work with Pascal and do something in something other than it should be, or to learn Java? thats my question,

---

---

thx for responses

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. The [help/on-topic] clearly states "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.". We also don't provide opinion-based answers, and whether it will be easier for you to learn Java or Pascal is entirely opinion, as we have absolutely no information about your learning abilities, background, or intelligence. Evaluate the two languages, see which one you seem to be able to learn more quickly, and make your own decision.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use the official Android Studio provided by Google as it will be a lot easier to search for problems/solutions when you're coding with the [Android&Java](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html) combination than [Android&Pascal](http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/Android_Programming)

Comment: This question is off-topic here (it's entirely opinion-based), and shouldn't be answered. The [help] has more information, if you're not sure what types of question are appropriate to ask here. Answering off-topic questions encourages more off-topic questions, and we try hard to keep noise and clutter down here to make the site more useful. Thanks.